# How to read this xml file generated by code metrics, in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio

**Read this xml file to get the method names and their cyclomatic value**
this is the xml file, i need to read the cyclomatic complexity value, and store the method name and the class containing that method in an object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    -<CodeMetricsReport Version="1.0">
    -<Targets>
    -<Target Name="ReadFileCS.csproj">
    -<Assembly Name="ReadFileCS, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    -<Metrics>
    <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="41"/>
    <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="19"/>
    <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="9"/>
    <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="1"/>
    <Metric Name="SourceLines" Value="149"/>
    <Metric Name="ExecutableLines" Value="40"/>
    </Metrics>
    -<Namespaces>
    -<Namespace Name="ReadFileCS">
    -<Metrics>
    <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="41"/>
    <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="19"/>
    <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="9"/>
    <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="1"/>
    <Metric Name="SourceLines" Value="149"/>
    <Metric Name="ExecutableLines" Value="40"/>
    </Metrics>
    -<Types>
    -<NamedType Name="Program">
    -<Metrics>
    <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="41"/>
    <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="19"/>
    <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="9"/>
    <Metric Name="DepthOfInheritance" Value="1"/>
    <Metric Name="SourceLines" Value="146"/>
    <Metric Name="ExecutableLines" Value="40"/>
    </Metrics>
    -<Members>
    -<Method Name="void Program.Main(string[] args)" Line="13" File="C:\Users\320117174\source\repos\ReadFileCS\ReadFileCS\Program.cs">
    -<Metrics>
    <Metric Name="MaintainabilityIndex" Value="41"/>
    <Metric Name="CyclomaticComplexity" Value="19"/>
    <Metric Name="ClassCoupling" Value="9"/>
    <Metric Name="SourceLines" Value="142"/>
    <Metric Name="ExecutableLines" Value="40"/>
    </Metrics>
    </Method>
    </Members>
    </NamedType>
    </Types>
    </Namespace>
    </Namespaces>
    </Assembly>
    </Target>
    </Targets>
    </CodeMetricsReport>
```

Comment: What does `read` mean? What is the question? .NET has a *lot* of ways to read XML and search for specific elements and values. There are a *lot* of SO questions about XmlDocument, XDocument, XPath or LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code by using **linq to xml** to get all the cyclometic value and the correspond Method Name and Class Name.

```
        string path = @"Test.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var result = doc.Descendants("Metric").Where(i => i.Attribute("Name").Value == "CyclomaticComplexity");
        foreach (XElement item in result)
        {
            if(item.Parent.Parent.Name.ToString()=="Method")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("Name").Value + " is " + item.Attribute("Value").Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Method is "+item.Parent.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Class Name is "+item.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("***********************");
        }

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou, this can work, but i do not have to read all the cyclomatic complexity, i just have to read the cyclomatic complexity of methods, and name of the class containing that method. Please update this code according to this

Comment: @Priya Rani, I have updated it, you can check if it works for you.

Comment: yes thankyou so much, i did the same thing. i also edited your code. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please write the code to read this xml file, as above in c# . i need the name of those assembly whose coverage percentage is less than 95... the xml file is.... i am appending in previous one @jack

Comment: @Priya Rani, it is better for you to ask a new question about it.

Comment: i know but i didn't understand it. after seeing one more code, may be i can understand properly

Comment: @Priya Rani, What  don't you understand？

Comment: That first line  in the begining var result = doc.Descendants("Metric").Where(i => i.Attribute("Name").Value == "CyclomaticComplexity");

Comment: @Priya Rani, this is used to find the element collection that name value is equal to CyclomaticComplexity in the Metric element.

Comment: if i dont want to check with the name? then. like what i posted now, according to that? what should be written

Comment: @Priya Rani, I suggest that you don't change your current question and ask another question. I recommend that you can ask a new question. If so, many people will help you here. Also, please restore the original question to prevent other members from having similar questions so that they can find the answer

Comment: okay, i am asking it in other question. thankyou so much for suggestion

Comment: hi, i have posted another question please tell answer

Answer (score 0):

I made littlte changes in your code, and got the exact result that was needed by me

```
  public static void main(string[] args)
    {
     string path = @"C:\Users\320117174\source\Report1.xml";
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
                var result = doc.Descendants("Metric").Where(i => i.Attribute("Name").Value == "CyclomaticComplexity");
                foreach (XElement item in result)
                {
                   // Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("Name").Value + " is " + item.Attribute("Value").Value);
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Attribute("Value").Value) > 5)
                    {
                       
                        if (item.Parent.Parent.Name.ToString() == "Method")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("Name").Value + " is " + item.Attribute("Value").Value);
                            Console.WriteLine("Method is " + item.Parent.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value);
                            Console.WriteLine("Class Name is " + item.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value);
                            Console.WriteLine("***********************");
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                Console.ReadKey();
    }
```